# How to Install Flash Debug Version for Google Chrome?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, google-chrome, flash

I installed Flash debug version (10.1) and it works fine with Firefox but it seems that in Google Chrome I have only the regular flash version and not the debug version.

Any ideas why? Do I need to install a different flash package specifically for Google Chrome?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Chrome now [includes a built-in version of Adobe Flash](http://techcrunch.com/2010/06/25/google-chrome-flash/) for security purposes (this ensures that Chrome users are always using the most recent version of Flash, since Chrome is automatically updated).

If you go to `about:plugins` in Chrome, you should be able to disable the built-in Flash plugin. This should cause Chrome to use your system's Flash.